# Prevent background scrolling in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want prevent scrolling background when I display a fixed full width/height div.

After many hours of test and research, i do this :

.navbar is my full width/height div

```
$('.navbar').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
})

$('.navbar').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  $('html, body').css('overflow', 'auto');
})
```

Its works on some devices, but is there a better way?

Thanks

EDIT : I want to block the scrolling of the background on ios, only scroll on fixed div on top of the whole page
my solution work, but its a good one ?

Comment: `background-attachment:fixed;`

Comment: what 'background' are you having problems with?  if it's an image, have you tried `#yourElementWithBackground { background-attachment: fixed; }`?

Comment: Do you mean the whole page or just bg?

Comment: Primarily opinion based bc he is asking if it’s a good idea? As in, will this have undesired consequences, WHICH IS NOT AN OPINION?

Comment: Fixed it. Crimany.

Comment: "scrolling background" means what? Do you mean make it so the page is not scrollable?

Comment: I don't have any problem, but I see many post, javascript code to do the same thing,  often complicated and inefficient. so im surprised the the solution are so easy .... so I doubt its a good idea ...

Comment: Still, clarify what your code does or people will not be able to tell you if there is a problem or improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to prevent scrolling entire document body, then your code won't achieve this result on latest iOS Safari. This is because Apple is really stubborn about blocking this option for developers for some reason. But there is one way to do it, which I tested many times:

1. On block, save current `var offsetTop = window.scrollTop`
2. Set in css `body: {position: fixed}`
3. Call using JS: `document.body.scrollTo(0, -offsetTop)`

Then on release:

1. Set in css `body: {position: <relative|static>}`
2. Call using JS: `document.body.scrollTo(0, 0)`

This is a little tricky, but is 100% sure to block scrolling on every device (until Apple discovers a way to block this on too).

Comment: You might also need something like `body: {width: 100%}` to prevent body from jumping when `position: fixed` is applied and removed.

Comment: Okayyyy ! I figured it was too simple, thanks for this.

Comment: @Johan If this ends up answering your question, be sure to mark it as accepted (click the checkmark, above).